# Como detectar colisão em jogo simples em html, javascript?

Tags: html, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Jogo</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas id="jogo" width="1000" height="600" style="border: #000 solid 1px;"> </canvas>  
    <script>  
        var canvas = document.getElementById('jogo'); 
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //definir o inicio do quadrado
        var x = 55;
        var x_largura = 40;
        var y = 280;
        var y_largura = 40;
        var dx = 5;
        var dy = 5;

        requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);

        function detectarColisao() {
            if ((x + x_largura) > (950, 0))
        {
          //interrompe o game loop parando a movimentação dos quadrados
          clearTimeout(); 
        }
        else {
            //chama novamente o ciclo da animação
            requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
        }
        }

        function gameloop(){
            desenharQuadrado(x,y);
            detectarColisao();
        }

        // DESENHO DO GAME
        //linha verde vertical com espessura de 5px
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; //cor dos traçados
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'; //cor do preenchimento
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;//espessura da linha
        ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        ctx.moveTo(50, 50); 
        ctx.lineTo(950, 50); 
        ctx.lineTo(950, 550); 
        ctx.lineTo(50, 550); 
        ctx.lineTo(50, 50); 
        ctx.stroke(); //traçar as linhas
        //ctx.fill(); //preencher o objeto formato

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(50,50);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 250);
        ctx.lineTo(50, 250);
        ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
        ctx.stroke(); //traçar as linhas
        ctx.fill(); //preencher o objeto formato

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(50, 550);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 550);
        ctx.lineTo(150, 350);
        ctx.lineTo(50, 350);
        ctx.lineTo(50, 550);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(200, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(400, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(400, 275);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 275);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(200, 500);
        ctx.lineTo(400, 500);
        ctx.lineTo(400, 325);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 325);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 500);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(450, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(450, 150);
        ctx.lineTo(600, 150);
        ctx.lineTo(600, 50);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(450, 200);
        ctx.lineTo(450, 400);
        ctx.lineTo(650, 400);
        ctx.lineTo(650, 200);
        ctx.lineTo(450, 200);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(450, 550);
        ctx.lineTo(450, 450);
        ctx.lineTo(600, 450);
        ctx.lineTo(600, 550);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(650, 200);
        ctx.lineTo(650, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(800, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(800, 500);
        ctx.lineTo(650, 500);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(850, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(950, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(950, 250);
        ctx.lineTo(850, 250);
        ctx.lineTo(850, 50);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.moveTo(850, 550);
        ctx.lineTo(950, 550);
        ctx.lineTo(950, 350);
        ctx.lineTo(850, 350);
        ctx.lineTo(850, 550);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        // FIM DO DESENHO DO GAME

        function desenharQuadrado(x,y) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 0, 0); //antes de fazer o desenho é preciso limpar o canvas
            ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, x_largura, y_largura);
        }

        function gameloop() {
            desenharQuadrado(x,y);
            //chama novamente o ciclo da animação
            requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
        }

        window.onkeydown = pressionaTecla;

        var velocidade = 2;

        function pressionaTecla(tecla){
            if(tecla.keyCode == 39  ) {
                x = x + 5; //aumentar o x tem o efeito de ir para a direita     
            }
            if(tecla.keyCode == 37  ) {
                x = x - 5; //diminuir o x tem o efeito de ir para a esquerda
            }
            if(tecla.keyCode == 38  ) {
                y = y - 5;
            }
            if(tecla.keyCode == 40  ) {
                y = y + 5;
            }
        }


        </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tem que usar uma estrutura de dados com as propriedades do mapa e do jogador

Comment: @tomasantunes por favor, poderia me dar um exemplo apenas da borda principal do mapa?

Comment: a borda pode ficar igual, falta o tilemap